# Proper capitalization when using __bases__ as a parameter

Tags: python, naming, camelcasing

I have a long, but simple linear hierarchy. My `Grandparent` class needs to provide a common `_something` method for all children (however distant), but the thing is it needs to call a `NextClass` when it's done.

In this case, the `NextClass` is always the parent.

Is it considered alright to do this:

```
class Grandparent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _something(self, NextClass):
        print "I did something."
        return NextClass()

class Parent(Grandparent):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Parent called.'
        super(Parent, self).__init__()

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()

    def _special_something(self):
        self._something(self.__bases__[0])


'Parent called.'
'I did something.'
'Parent called.'
```

How do I better convey what is going on here?

```
def _special_something(self):
    parent_class = self.__bases__[0]
    self._something(parent_class)
```

Which is explicit, but it looks like an instance. This breaks naming convention, but I think is clearer.

```
def _special_something(self):
    ParentClass = self.__bases__[0]
    self._something(ParentClass)
```

"Variables" aren't supposed to be camel-cased, but is this a variable? When everything is an object, it gets hard to tell where the rules apply.

Comment: It is a variable, and as such `parent_class` is more appropriate.